# Visiting Facebook Pages with urllib and Get Past Login in Python

Tags: python, facebook, urllib

I'm working on a project that requires me to sign in to Facebook, with an account that I have already made. I am using the `urllib` module to visit the website. When I visit it though, it opens the page without being signed in to a account. For example, with "https://www.facebook.com/", you visit the Facebook homepage when you are signed in, but the login page when you're not.

The question is, how do I visit a Facebook page with an account, so I can get past the login page? Is there something else I must do? Visit another URL, perhaps? Please answer this question if you can.

Thanks!

Comment: To achieve this, you would probably have to send some cookies with your request. However, Facebook does not want programmatic access to their website, so they make it intentionally hard to do what you are trying to do. To be honest, I would not spend too much time trying to get this to work. Instead, maybe have a look at the official "Facebook for developers" site here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview

Comment: I have taken a look at the Graph API before, however I find APIs hard to work with, so I prefer easier alternatives like automation and web scraping. The API will be my last resort, and I am searching for other alternatives.

Comment: Scraping a website like facebook.com is not "easy". Given the amount of JavaScript used and general complexity of their site, I'd go so far as to say that it is completely infeasible, especially if you are not very experienced. The API is your best bet. In any case though, I wish you the best of luck :)